# Solve $x^3 = 27\pmod {41}$

Tags: number-theory

I don't know how to approach this problem. Can anyone give me a hint? If it matters, the first part of the question was to find the order of $5$ in the field $\mathbb Z_{41}$ (the field mod $41$), which I did, but I'm not sure how it relates to the second part.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: $x^3-3^3=(x-3)(x^2+3x+9)$

Comment: @NotMe And $14$ is not a square modulo $41$.

Comment: @egreg: Do you mean $24$? Your statement is true, but I don't see how it applies, offhand.

Comment: @CameronBuie The discriminant of the quadratic factor is $9-36=-27\equiv14\pmod{41}$, so the factor has no root.

Comment: Ah! I see your thought now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The previous answers are nice, general(izable), and elegant (+1 to each). Let's take a look at this using another, perhaps more familiar (but tedious) approach.

The following are equivalent: $$x^3=27\pmod{41}\\x^3-27=0\pmod{41}\\x^3-3^3=0\pmod{41}\\(x-3)\left(x^2+3x+3^2\right)=0\pmod{41}$$ Since $41$ is prime, then in general, $ab=0\pmod{41}$ if and only if $a=0\pmod{41}$ or $b=0\pmod{41}.$ So, we know that $$x-3=0\pmod{41}\qquad\text{or}\qquad x^2+3x+3^2=0\pmod{41}\\x=3\pmod{41}\qquad\text{or}\qquad x^2+3x+9=0\pmod{41}.$$ The following are equivalent: $$x^2+3x+9=0\pmod{41}\\x^2+3x=-9\pmod{41}\\x^2+(3+41)x=-9\pmod{41}\\x^2+44x=-9\pmod{41}\\x(x+44)=-9\pmod{41}\\(x+22-22)(x+22+22)=-9\pmod{41}\\(x+22)^2-22^2=-9\pmod{41}\\(x+22)^2-484=-9\pmod{41}\\(x+22)^2=475\pmod{41}\\(x+22)^2=11\cdot 41+24\pmod{41}\\(x+22)^2=24\pmod{41}$$ If you happen to know the [quadratic residues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue) *modulo* $41$--in particular, that $24$ *isn't* one, then we're done, as we can conclude that there is no $y$ such that $y^2=24\pmod{41}.$ If you don't, then they are fairly quickly calculated, since $41$ is a fairly small odd prime. It is a fact that, for any odd prime $p,$ there are $(p+1)/2$ quadratic residues--$21$ in this case. The various residues are fairly quickly found, recalling that the non-zero squares are sums of consecutive odd numbers. So, aside from the first seven obvious squares ($0,1,4,9,16,25,36$), we have (all of the following are congruences *modulo* $41$):
$$36+13=-5+13=8\\8+15=23\\23+17=40\\40+19=-1+19=18\\18+21=39\\39+23=-2+23=21\\21+25=-20+25=5\\5+27=32\\32+29=-9+29=20\\20+31=-21+31=10\\10+33=-31+33=2\\2+35=37\\37+37=-4+37=33\\33+39=-8+39=31$$

So, our set of quadratic residues *modulo* $41$ is $\{0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 16, 18, 20, 21, 23, 25, 31, 32, 33, 36, 37, 39, 40\},$ meaning $24$ is not a perfect square *modulo* $41,$ and so only $x=3\pmod{41}$ is a solution.

Comment: Thank you so much for this!

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 9):

The obvious solution is $3$.

Can there be multiple cube roots of the same number in a field? That can only happen if there is a non-trivial cube root of $1$ in the field (why?)

But there is no element of order $3$ in $\mathbb Z_{41}$ (why?)

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** $\ {\rm mod}\ 41\!:\  x^{\large\color{#c00}3}\equiv 3^{\large\color{#c00}3}\!\!\iff\! x\equiv 3\ $ by raising to $\rm\color{#c00}{power\ \ 27\equiv 1/3}  \pmod{\!40},\,$ via $\,\rm\color{#0a0}{\mu Fermat}.$

i.e. $\ \ 3\cdot 27 = 1 + 2\cdot 40\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{(a^{\large 3})^{\large 27}}\!\equiv a^{\large 1+2\cdot 40}\equiv a(\color{#0a0}{a^{40}})^2\equiv a(\color{#0a0}1)^2\equiv \color{#c00}a,\ $ by $\,\color{#0a0}{a^{40}\equiv 1\ \ \ {\rm for}\ \ a\not\equiv 0}$

Said much more simply:  $\ \ \color{#c00}{(a^{\large 3})^{\large 1/3} \equiv\, a},\, $ by $1/3$ exists mod $\, 40,\,$ by $\gcd(3,40)=1\,$ and Bezout.

**Remark** $\ $ The proof needs only: $\,3$ is invertible mod $40 =\phi(41),\,$ i.e. we don't need to know the specific value of $\,1/3$ $(\equiv 27).$ But knowing this value is very handy since it allows us to quickly compute cube roots: $ $  powering to $\ 1/3 \equiv 27\pmod{40}\ $ shows, like above, that

$$ {\rm mod}\ 41\!:\,\   x^3\!\equiv a \iff\! x\equiv a^{27},\ \  {\rm i.e.}\,\ \ \color{#c00}{a^{1/3}\equiv a^{27}}$$

Thus we have reduced cube-root computation to the simpler problem of computing powers, which can done quickly by repeated squaring.

The same holds for $\,n$'th powers mod $m$ when $n$ is coprime to $m$, since then $\,1/n = n^{-1}$ exists by Bezout. $ $ This shows that the map $\,x\mapsto x^n$ has  inverse $\,x\mapsto x^k,$ where $\,k\equiv 1/n\pmod{\phi(m)},\,$ when the map is restricted to elements $a$ coprime to $m$.  The innate algebraic structure at the heart of the matter will become clearer when one studies group theory (in particular cyclic groups).

Comment: I don't how you used Fermat's Little Theorem here.

Comment: @Mark I added further detail.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 4):

Since $\phi(41)=40$, $x^{40}\equiv1\pmod{41}$. This means that $x^{81}\equiv x\pmod{41}$. Therefore,
$$
\left(x^3\right)^{27}\equiv x\pmod{41}
$$
This means that if we know $x^3$ mod $41$, we know $x$ mod $41$. Since $3^3=27$, $x=3$ can be the only one.

Comment: You lost me in the last line. You showed that $x$ should equal $(x^3)^{27}$, and using the fact that $x^3 \equiv 27$ you get $x \equiv 27^{27}$. So how do you see that $x \equiv 3$ is the only solution (without computing $27^{27}$)?

Comment: @TMM: We know that $\left(3^3\right)^{27}\equiv 3\pmod{41}$; that is $27^{27}\equiv 3\pmod{41}$. Suppose that $14^3\equiv 27\pmod{41}$. Then $\left(14^3\right)^{27}\equiv 14\pmod{41}$; that is $27^{27}\equiv 14\pmod{41}$, but we just said that $27^{27}\equiv 3\pmod{41}$.

Comment: I don't see how it is obvious that "we know that $(3^3)^{27} \equiv 3$" from your answer. I suppose you wanted to avoid the computation of $27^{27}$ by arguing that (1) knowing $x^3$ implies knowing $x$ uniquely, and (2) $x = 3$ is a solution because it satisfies $x^3 \equiv 27$. Anyway, the last line had me confused because I did not understand that by $3^3 = 27$ you meant that $x^3 \equiv 27$ has a solution at $x \equiv 3$.

Comment: @TMM: We know that $\left(3^3\right)^{27}\equiv3\pmod{41}$ because we showed that $x^{81}\equiv x\pmod{41}$. Since $3^3=27$, we know that $27^{27}\equiv3\pmod{41}$.

Answer (score 0):

We shall use the lemma that if $a^r\equiv a^s\pmod{n}$, then $r\equiv s\pmod{\operatorname{ord}_n(a)}$. Note that $6$ is a primitive root $\pmod{41}$, and that $6^5\equiv 27\pmod{41}$. We can write $x^3 = 6^{3k}$ for some $k$, so that $$6^{3k}\equiv 6^5\pmod{41}\implies 3k\equiv 5\pmod{\varphi(41)=40}.$$ It is straightforward to proceed from here.